# What is a valid target for Spam Assassin's sa-learn?

Tags: spamassassin

I'd like to train my Spam Assassin with some spam that it's missed, however I'm confused. With `sa-learn` I could target:

- raw message
- text-message (body)
- html (body)

What one of those options is this best. I'd like to pull the message right out of my E-mail box. Is it of any concern if the raw-message has in the header's destination my e-mail address? Will that perhaps confuse its ability to learn spam from ham?

Any other suggestions about `sa-learn`ing

Answer (score 10):

I use the raw message. There's no need to trim the messages before running sa-learn.

Comment: An advantage of using the raw message is that sa-learn can also process the headers, which may be more useful than the body itself.

Comment: As long as you give it separate `--ham` and `--spam` runs, it's all good.